# I am getting an stack error,"an integer is required (got type str)"...please tell

Tags: python, stack

**Problem encountered while practicing stack**
I was making a program for placing rings in a ring stand such that the ring having the lower radius is below the higher radius ring. For doing so I used sort(reverse="True") function for sorting my stack though every element of stack for an integer it showed be an error stating i am using strings.
Please tell where i went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Omit the quotes around `True`! You need to write

```
your_list.sort(reverse=True)
```